# SQL Server: Concatenating WHERE Clauses. Seeking Appropriate Pattern

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, select, concatenation

I want to take a poorly designed SQL statement that's embedded in C# code and rewrite it as a stored procedure (presumably), and am looking for an appropriate means to address the following pattern:

```
sql = "SELECT <whatever> FROM <table> WHERE 1=1";

if ( someCodition.HasValue )
{
    sql += " AND <some-field> = " + someCondition.Value;
}
```

This is a simplification. The actual statement is quite long and contains several such conditions, some of which include `INNER JOIN`'s to other tables if the condition is present. This last part is key, otherwise I'd *probably* be able to solve all of them with:

```
WHERE <some-condition-value> IS NULL OR <some-field> = <some-condition-value>
```

I can think of a few possible approaches. I'm looking for the *correct* approach.

**Edit:**
I don't want to perform concatenation in C#. I consider this a serious compromise to security.

Comment: Be sure to avoid Sql Injection.

Comment: @Pierre: we're in agreement here. I suppose my question could be phrased "how to concatenate a SQL statement without actually performing concatenation."

Comment: I have updated my answer see if its helpful..

Comment: @Binoj - all the answers have been helpful! Fortunately, I have enough lead time to turn this into a solid learning experience, so I'm going to read through the document that @KM refers to before proceeding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, the idea is to replace a whole section of code in C# in charge of producing, "long hand", a specific SQL statement corresponding to a list of search criteria, by a single call to a stored-procedure which would, SQL-side, use a generic template of the query aimed at handling all allowed combinations of search criteria in a uniform fashion.

In addition to the difficulty of mapping expressions evaluated on the application-side (eg. someCondition.HasValue) to expressions evaluated on the SQL-side (eg  "some-condition-value"), the solution you envision may be **logically/functionally equivalent** to a "hand-crafted" SQL statement, but **slower and more demanding of SQL resources**.

Essentially, the C# code encapsulates **specific knowledge about the "physical" layout of the database and its schema**.  It uses this info to figure-out when a particular JOIN may be required or when a particular application-level search criteria value translate to say a SQL "LIKE" rather than an "=" predictate.  It may also encaspsulate business rules such as "when the ZIP code is supplied, search by that rather than by State".

**You are right to attempt and decouple the data model** (the way the application sees the data) **from the data schema** (the way it is declared and stored in SQL), but the proper mapping needs to be done somehow, somewhere.
Doing this at the level of the application, with all the expressive power of C# as opposed to say T-SQL, is not necessarily a bad thing, provided it is done
   - in a module that is independent of other features of the application 
and, where practical,
   - it is somewhat data/configuration-driven as so to allow small changes in the data model (say the addition of a search criteria) to be implemented by changing a configuration file, rather than plugging this in somewhere in the middle of a long series of C# conditional statements.

Comment: Accepted: Three excellent answers. Yours made me to the most thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can start with

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("SELECT <whatever> FROM <table> WHERE  1 = 1 ");

if ( someCodition.HasValue )
{
    sb.Append(" AND <some-field> = " + someCondition.Value);
}

// And so on
```

Will save you the trouble of putting the first WHERE - AND

[Edit]

You can also try this

Create an SP with all required parameters for the table, and write the query like this.

```
DECLARE @sqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)

 @sqlStatement = " SELECT fields1, fields2 FROM TableA WHERE  1 = 1 "
if(@param1 IS NOT NULL)  @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement + "AND Column1 = " + @param1
if(@param2 IS NOT NULL)  @sqlStatement = @sqlStatement + "AND Column2 = " + @param2
// and so on 

sp_executeSql @sqlStatement
```

Also you can try similar SP but with:

```
SELECT fields1, fields2 FROM TableA WHERE  1 = 1 
AND ( ( @param1 IS NULL ) OR ( Column1 = @param1 ) )
AND ( ( @param2 IS NULL ) OR ( Column2 = @param2 ) )
```

this is definitely injection proof!

Comment: The first WHERE I have handled. I'm looking for a way to do this with parameterization or within a view or stored procedure, so as to avoid the pitfalls of concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

start with this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE 1=1
```

then append all conditions as:

```
AND <some-field> = " + someCondition.Value;
```

the optimizer will toss out the 1=1 condition and you don't have to worry about too many ANDs

**EDIT** based on OP's comment about not wanting to concatinate strings:

here is a very comprehensive article on how to handle this topic:

[Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html)

it covers all the issues and methods of trying to write queries with multiple optional search conditions

here is the table of contents:

```
  Introduction
      The Case Study: Searching Orders
      The Northgale Database
   Dynamic SQL
      Introduction
      Using sp_executesql
      Using the CLR
      Using EXEC()
      When Caching Is Not Really What You Want
   Static SQL
      Introduction
      x = @x OR @x IS NULL
      Using IF statements
      Umachandar's Bag of Tricks
      Using Temp Tables
      x = @x AND @x IS NOT NULL
      Handling Complex Conditions
   Hybrid Solutions – Using both Static and Dynamic SQL
      Using Views
      Using Inline Table Functions
   Conclusion
   Feedback and Acknowledgements
   Revision History
```

Comment: We're in agreement starting with WHERE 1=1. I want to avoid performing concatenation in C#, per @Pierre's comment.

Comment: Thank you, KM, for finding the 'Dynamic Search Cond..." article.  It is indeed very thorough, but, fairly enough, only attempts to address this at the level of SQL.  Also, (at a quick glance) does not attempt to somehow objectify/data-ify the search model, hence the fixed API (to be changed each time a new search criteria is added).  In effect the approaches discussed in this article would allow to merely move "some ugly code" out of C# and into SQL.

Comment: I'm confused now. I have no idea what you are after. do you want a C# solution? TSQL solution? dynamic sql? fixed sql? there are only so many ways to do WHERE conditions

Comment: @KM - I'm after the *right* solution! It could be C# concatenation, C# parameterization, a stored procedure, LINQ to SQLm etc. :)

Comment: with dynamic search conditions, there usually is no _perfect solution_, you just have to decide what trade offs you can live with